# Why Intent constructor is invisible in companion object? Kotlin

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-adapter

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        fun makeIntent(pos : Int) {
            println("${pos} is here!")
            var intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
            if (intent != null) {
                println("intent is not null in makeIntent function")
            }   else {
                println("intent is null in makeIntent function")
            }
        }
    }

    ... 
}
```

While doing `var intent = Intent(...)` it does not see Intent. Why?

Answer (score 2):

`Intent` constructor requires `Context` passed as an argument. Inside `makeIntent` `this` is a reference to the instance of [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects). A companion object has no reference to the instance of containing class. Hence you'd have to pass the `Context` somehow e.g.:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        fun makeIntent(pos : Int, context:Context):Intent {
            println("${pos} is here!")
            var intent = Intent(context, DetailActivity::class.java)
            return intent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @meinsol's excellent answer, you can keep your code pretty much the same if you add a receiver to the `makeIntent` function:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        fun Context.makeIntent(pos : Int) {  // <- Notice the Context receiver here
            println("${pos} is here!")
            var intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
            // Do what you want with the intent
        }
    }

    ... 
}
```

Then you can call it from anywhere you are in a context (`makeIntent(5)`), or if you're not in a context but have one available, use it (`context.makeIntent(5)`)